# How to show specific answer from Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, machine-learning, nlp, n-gram

I am using Elasticsearch for storing page-wise documents. When I am doing full text search it returns me the whole content of the page that has best score. I want to show user **only specific section of the page that has the answer** and not the whole content of the page.

What is the best way to achieve that?

I saw google use something called ngram document viewer and limit the viewer only to specific answer segment of that page. I want something similar in Elasticsearch.

Please give me some hints or suggestions.

Comment: You want to show the section that matched the query or some other section in the text?

Comment: I want to show the section that matched the query. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-highlighting.html)!

Here's a Kibana-ready example starting from scratch, assuming you're storing the whole page html, not just plain text (although highlighting works just fine with plain text too):

1.

```
PUT my_index
```

2.

```
POST my_index/snippets/1
{
  "html_text": """
  <div class="top10">
    <h4>Top References</h4>
    <a href="/tags/default.asp">HTML Reference</a><br>
    <a href="/cssref/default.asp">CSS Reference</a><br>
    <a href="/jsref/default.asp">JavaScript Reference</a><br>
    <a href="/sql/sql_ref_keywords.asp">SQL Reference</a><br>
    <a href="/python/python_reference.asp">Python Reference</a><br>
    <a href="/w3css/w3css_references.asp">W3.CSS Reference</a><br>
    <a href="/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_all_classes.asp">Bootstrap Reference</a><br>
    <a href="/php/php_ref_overview.asp">PHP Reference</a><br>
    <a href="/colors/colors_names.asp">HTML Colors</a><br>
    <a href="/jquery/jquery_ref_overview.asp">jQuery Reference</a><br>
    <a href="/java/java_ref_keywords.asp">Java Reference</a><br>
    <a href="/angular/angular_ref_directives.asp">Angular Reference</a><br>
  </div>
"""
}
```

3.

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "html_text": "href"
    }
  },
  "_source": "highlight",
  "size": 10,
  "highlight": {
    "number_of_fragments": 1,
    "fragment_size": 12,
    "fields": {
      "html_text": {
        "number_of_fragments": 2,
        "order": "score",
        "pre_tags": [
          "<strong>"
        ],
        "post_tags": [
          "</strong>"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which yields

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.575738,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "snippets",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.575738,
        "_source": {},
        "highlight": {
          "html_text": [
            "</a><br>\n<a <strong>href</strong>",
            "</a><br>\n<a <strong>href</strong>"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can specify how many fragments you'd like and how long they should be. If matched, they'll be accessible in the `hits[].highlight` part of the response.